# vscode snippet - transform and replace filename

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

my filename is

> some-fancy-ui.component.html

I want to use a vscode snippet to transform it to

> SOME_FANCY_UI

So basically

1. apply upcase to each character
2. Replace all - with _
3. Remove .component.html

Currently I have

> '${TM_FILENAME/(.*)(-)(.*)/${1:/upcase}${2:/_}${3:/upcase}/g}'

which gives me this

> 'SETUP-PRINTER-SERVER-LIST.COMPONENT.HTML'

The docs doesn't explain how to apply replace in combination with their transforms on regex groups.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If the chunks you need to upper are separated with `-` or `.` you may use

```
"Filename to UPPER_SNAKE_CASE": {
    "prefix": "usc_",
    "body": [
        "${TM_FILENAME/\\.component\\.html$|(^|[-.])([^-.]+)/${1:+_}${2:/upcase}/g}"
    ],
    "description": "Convert filename to UPPER_SNAKE_CASE dropping .component.html at the end"
}
```

You may check the [regex workings here](https://regex101.com/r/L4Jsj7/1).

- `\.component\.html$` - matches `.component.html` at the end of the string
- `|` - or
- `(^|[-.])` capture start of string or `-` / `.` into Group 1
- `([^-.]+)` capture any 1+ chars other than `-` and `.` into Group 2.

The `${1:+_}${2:/upcase}` replacement means:

- `${1:+` - if Group 1 is not empty,
- `_` - replace with `_`
- `}` - end of the first group handling
- `${2:/upcase}` - put the uppered Group 2 value back.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a pretty simple alternation regex:

```
"upcaseSnake": {
  "prefix": "rf1",
  "body": [
    "${TM_FILENAME_BASE/(\\..*)|(-)|(.)/${2:+_}${3:/upcase}/g}",

    "${TM_FILENAME/(\\..*)|(-)|(.)/${2:+_}${3:/upcase}/g}"
  ],
  "description": "upcase and snake the filename"
},
```

Either version works.

`(\\..*)|(-)|(.)` alternation of three capture groups is conceptually simple.  The order of the groups is **important**, and it is also what makes the regex so simple.

`(\\..*)` everything after and including the first dot `.` in the filename goes into group 1 which will not be used in the transform.

`(-)` group 2, if there is a group 2, replace it with an underscore `${2:+_}`.

`(.)` group 3, all other characters go into group 3 which will be upcased `${3:/upcase}`.

See [regex101 demo](http://some-fancy-ui.html).