# How to convert filename like Account-Manager.hpp to __ACCOUNT_MANAGER_HPP__ in VSCode snippets?

Tags: vscode-snippets

I am trying to write a VScode snippet to convert the filename to a unique string so that it can be used in the header's include pragma.

For example, if the filename is `Account-Manager.hpp` then I want to convert it into `__ACCOUNT_MANAGER_HPP__`.

To covert filename to all caps, `"${TM_FILENAME/(.*)/${1:/upcase}/}",`

To replace all `-` and `.` to `_`, `"${TM_FILENAME/(.*)/${1:/upcase}/}",`

Not able to combine two regexes into a single one!

**Answer**:
 `__${TM_FILENAME/(^|[-.])([^-.]+)/${1:+_}${2:/upcase}/g}__"`

**Reference**: [vscode snippet - transform and replace filename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56793075/vscode-snippet-transform-and-replace-filename)

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution as below:

The double operation can be done with multiple captures as below:
`__${TM_FILENAME/(^|[-.])([^-.]+)/${1:+_}${2:/upcase}/g}__"`